# javascript regex and trim everything after "dash"

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, trim

For the html below, I am trying to put a variable to just "oakbarrels" and a variable to just "Dec 25, 2011".  I have already been able to get the "Dec 25, 2011" with regex but I cannot figure out how to get the rest.  Basically I want to remove "By " and everything after the first " -":

```
<p class="review-rating">
         By oakbarrels
         - Dec 25, 2011
         -
         Something.com
</p>
<script>
    var thedate =  $('.review-rating').text().match(/\-\s([^\n]+)/)[1].trim();
    var from = ???
</script>
```

Comment: That's more of a JavaScript question than a jQuery question. jQuery does not have a regex engine.

Comment: Agreed, I have updated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var matches = $('.review-rating').text().match(/\s*By\s+(\w+)\s*-\s*([\w, ]+)/);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQXNQ/).

`matches[1]` will contain `'oakbarrels'` and `matches[2]` will contain `'Dec 25, 2011'`, as per your example.

I also changed your `html()` to `text()`. It doesn't appear the HTML is relevant to matching the text.

Comment: still having a brief issue: http://jsfiddle.net/AQXNQ/1/  Trying to do this on more than one p tag, any ideas?

Comment: @ToddN The regex needs to capture more than just `\w`. [Check](http://jsfiddle.net/GYSbR/).

Comment: Brilliant, that did it.  I just needed the `\w` for multiple <p> tags.

Comment: Still having a brief issue for "By's" with a dash see here: http://jsfiddle.net/AQXNQ/2/

Comment: @ToddN Just add the characters to your character class.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string first. You don't even need regular expressions:

```
var parts = $('.review-rating').text().split('-');
var date  = $.trim(parts[1])
var from  = $.trim(parts[0]).substring(3);
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/KwdYr/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to match multiple lines.

```
var text = $('.review-rating').text();
var matches = text.match(/(.+?)-\s*(.+?)(?:\n|\A)/m);
//matches[1] = oakberrels
//matches[2] = Dec 25, 2011
```